# How to add data to arraylist in java?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, spinner, addition

i create spinner to filter data in list.
i've data list  and i want to add in arraylist, 
example my code :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


        ArrayList<MScheduleEvent.data> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();


        list_model.clear();
        for (MScheduleEvent.data m: _model){
            if (label.compareTo("ALL")==0 || m.getCategory().compareToIgnoreCase(label) == 0) {
                MScheduleEvent.data data = new MScheduleEvent.data(
                        m.getId(),
                        m.getName(),
                        m.getDescription(),
                        m.getDay(),
                        m.getDate(),
                        m.getTime(),
                        m.getPlace()
            }
            filteredList.add(data); // ERROR
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```

but i want to add data in filteredList always error "add(MSchedule.data) in java.util.arraylist cannot be applied to java.util.linkedlist "

Comment: This code won't even compile...can you clean it up a bit?

Comment: i havent tried your code, but, as @Gennadii said you sould do. And Then please notify to your adaptar that your data has been changed. Sample: Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `data` variable there because it's not visible due to its scope. Try this:

```
   for (MScheduleEvent.data m: _model){
        if (label.compareTo("ALL")==0 || m.getCategory().compareToIgnoreCase(label) == 0) {
            MScheduleEvent.data data = new MScheduleEvent.data(
                    m.getId(),
                    m.getName(),
                    m.getDescription(),
                    m.getDay(),
                    m.getDate(),
                    m.getTime(),
                    m.getPlace()
            filteredList.add(data);
        }

    }
```